# Not able to expand a field in drf

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, expand

I have a story model which has to field brand and company as a foreign key.
Now when trying to get a story through get a request I want to expand the brand and company of that particular story.
I am using `FlexFieldsModelSerializer` and have added the brand and company in the expandable fields but it still does not work.
Can someone please help me with it?

```
class Story(AbstractModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='brand')
    viewer = models.CharField(choices=VIEWER_CHOICES.choices,max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(choices=STORY_TYPES.choices, max_length=50)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Story"
        verbose_name_plural = "Stories"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} <{self.company}>"


class StorySerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    update_url = CustomURIField(view_name="core:story-detail")


    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = '__all__'

     expandable_fields = {
          "brand": ('core.BrandSerializer', {"source": "brand"}),
          "company": ('core.CompanySerializer', {"source": "company"}),
          "media": ('core.StoryImageSerializer', {"source": "media", 'many': True}),
     }
```

I am sending get request like this using postman {{ROOT_URL}}/api/v1/core/stories/?expand=company

```
 {
        "id": 54,
        "update_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/core/stories/54/",
        "media": [],
        "created_at": "2023-05-05T09:44:51.475030",
        "updated_at": "2023-05-05T09:44:51.475043",
        "viewer": "both",
        "text": "photo test",
        "type": "image",
        "company": 919,
        "brand": 21
```

As seen above I am not getting the company expanded.